# Material-UI: Uncaught TypeError: getMuiTheme is not a function

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I have recently updated my material-ui to version 0.15.4 and trying to make it work. The error i am getting is that getMuiTheme is not a function, even though the folder location contains the relvant js file, also i checked and updated my react to 15.3.1,so hopefully it's not a dependency issue. But i can't seem to figure out what could be the issue.

Here is the code sample:

```
var React = require('react'),
  mui = require('material-ui'),
  getMuiTheme = require('material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'),
  LoginDialog = require('./login-dialog.jsx'),
  RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton,
  MuiThemeProvider = require('material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'),
  darkBaseTheme = require('material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme');



var Index = React.createClass({

  getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme),
    };
  },

  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="mui-app-canvas home-page-background">
        <RaisedButton
          className="login-button"
          label="Login"
          onTouchTap={ this._handleLoginDialog }
          linkButton={ false } />
        <LoginDialog
          ref="loginDialog"
          loginUrl={ this.props.loginUrl } />
      </div>
    )
  },

  _handleLoginDialog: function() {
    this.refs.loginDialog.show();
  }
});

module.exports = Index;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme.js` is transpiled from an ES2015 source, and the function you want is exported as a default.

If you want to reference this function with `require()`, you need to use the `default` property:

```
getMuiTheme = require('material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme').default
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On another component, when i am adding the same childContextTypes. I am getting the following error "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `PortalPage`.". Do you have any idea what could be going wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: @AdityaPatel it sounds like you're trying to render an undefined reference. Perhaps you should create a new question for that, including some code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Following is the link to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164577/material-ui-error-element-type-is-invalid-after-updating-to-ver-0-15-4