# material-ui: Error: Element type is invalid (After updating to ver 0.15.4)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have recently updated material-ui to version 0.15.4 from 0.14.4 . I had to add getMuiTheme() to make it work in few components. But in one of the components, I am getting the following error and I am not able to understand what's happening.

**Error: "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of PortalPage"**

Code Snippet:

```
var React = require('react'),
  mui = require('material-ui'),
  Router = require('react-router'),
  axios = require('axios'),
  AppCanvas = mui.AppCanvas,
  AppBar = mui.AppBar,
  MenuItem = mui.MenuItem,
  //MenuItem = require('material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item')
  FlatButton = mui.FlatButton,
  PageWithNav = require('./page-with-nav.jsx'),
  getMuiTheme = require('material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme').default,
  darkBaseTheme = require('material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme');
  //ThemeManager = require('material-ui/lib/styles/theme-manager');


var PortalPage = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Router.Navigation],

  getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme),
    };
  },

  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },


  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loggedIn: auth.loggedIn()
    };
  },

  setStateOnAuth: function(loggedIn) {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: loggedIn
    });
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    auth.onChange = this.setStateOnAuth;

    // If they aren't logged in, send them back to the home screen
    if (!auth.loggedIn()) this.transitionTo('/');
  },

  render: function() {

    var logOutButton = (
    <FlatButton
      secondary={ true }
      label="Log Out"
      className="log-out-button"
      onTouchTap={ this._onLogOutButtonTouchTap } />
    );

    var menuItems = [
      {
        //     type: MenuItem.Types.SUBHEADER,
        text: 'Portal 1'
      },
      {
        route: 'portal-2',
        text: 'Portal 2'
      },
      {
        route: 'portal-3',
        text: 'Portal 3'
      }
    ];

    // nav bar is different for family users and doctors
    if (auth.isUser()) {
      menuItems = [
        {
          //      type: MenuItem.Types.SUBHEADER,
          text: 'Portal 4'
        },
        {
          route: 'portal-5',
          text: 'Portal 5'
        }
      ];
    }

    return (
      <AppCanvas predefinedLayout={ 1 }>
        <AppBar
          className="mui-dark-theme"
          iconElementRight={ logOutButton }
          onRightIconButtonTouchTap={ this._onLogOutButtonTouchTap }
          zDepth={ 0 } />
        <PageWithNav menuItems={ menuItems } />
      </AppCanvas>
    )
  },

  _onLogOutButtonTouchTap: function() {

    // Delete our user token
    auth.logout();

    // Tell the server to destroy our session, and clear our auth header
    axios.get(this.props.destroySessionUrl);
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "";

    this.transitionTo('/');
  }
});

module.exports = PortalPage;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Can you check the value of `PageWithNav` (`console.log(PageWithNav)` inside the `render` method)? One of the components that you use inside the `render` method is undefined. If `PageWithNav` isn't the culprit, try checking the others to make sure that they aren't undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @roberklep PageWithNav is another react component which creates menu items on the side bar. I don't understand how it can be undefined.

Comment: And the code was working in version 0.14.4

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string) (although it's _slightly_ different so may not apply as-is). Some element you're trying to use seems to be undefined. Could be because of a faulty import/require.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the link, it seems AppCanvas and AppBar are causing problems, once i remove them , i don't get header but my code starts working again. Any idea how to fix, most probably its AppCanvas. But still not able to link it all together.

Comment: `AppCanvas` isn't a component that MUI provides, perhaps it's from an older version? `AppBar` [does exist](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar). **EDIT**: `AppCanvas` seems to be part of another library ([`react-flux-mui`](https://github.com/thisbejim/react-flux-mui/blob/master/node_modules/material-ui/src/js/app-canvas.jsx)).